# Cannot reach API from localhost, but can from outside

Tags: node.js, api, ssl, woocommerce, ssl-certificate

I wrote an express API which wrap the WooCommerce API.

When I developped the app from my computer, I didn't have any trouble. But know that I put it on an Apache Server with Passenger on a subdomain like api.example.com, it returns me this error :

```
{
  "message": "certificate has expired",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "Error: certificate has expired\n    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1105:38)\n    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)\n    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:639:8)\n    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:469:38)",
  "config": {
    "url": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders",
    "method": "get",
    "params": {
      "per_page": 100
    },
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "User-Agent": "WooCommerce REST API - JS Client/1.0.1"
    },
    "auth": {
      "username": "_",
      "password": "_"
    },
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "responseType": "json",
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "responseEncoding": "utf8"
  },
  "code": "CERT_HAS_EXPIRED"
}
```

And when I curl directly the API from my server, it returns me that :

```
curl https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/400 -u consumer_key:consumer_secret
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

How could this error could be true if it didn't tell me that before ?

Here's my SSL configuration for the domain.

[image: SSL configuration]

Comment: were you running on https or http from localhost?

Comment: in any case, you need a legit SSL certificate to run your https service.

Comment: On http. Why don't I get this error when I start the application on my PC? And why doesn't my browser tell me that the certificate is not recognized? I find this weird. And just to be sure, If I put a valid certificate for example.com, it will be available directly for api.example.com, right? I just have to request the wildcart certificate?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I add my SSL configuration. Notice that my SSL certificate is valid.

Comment: api.example.com is a different domain than example.com. A wildcard certificate may work (although expensive), but still needs to be configured in Apache independently of example.com